# Can we customize email content at runtime

Tags: docusignapi

I have looked at several PDF uploaded on docusign website but didn't get success at all. My problem is I want to create a generic email template in my docusign account but want to update its uncommon(client specific) content dynamically using the Docusign Web-service API.

For example: Client Name, Client Address, Phone Number, Mobile number, Payment Amount, and Payment Last date are some fields whose values varies based on client whereas other content of the email is common for all, Hence I want to understand that is there any way so that I can set the values for this fields in WS call and docusign will use that common email template and replace the customized fields on the fly for every client.

We Will make one WS call for one client at a time. Please help it is quite crucial for us.

Currently we are creating email content to our side and set into the EmailBlur but want to do it more customized so in future we can make changes easily.

Quick response is highly appreciate!

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create/maintain an "email template" in DocuSign that contains placeholder variables for you to dynamically inject client-specific values into the email for each Envelope as part of the **Create Envelope** request.

To acheive your scenario, you'll need to create/maintain the email template contents within your application, and have your application dynamically generate the email contents for each Envelope.  Then you can simply set the Envelope's **emailBlurb** property (in the **Create Envelope** request) to the contents (i.e., full email body) that your application generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is Account related setting which needs to be enable by docusign, In my case I have contacted them and they made some changes after which the emailblurb method start supporting HTML.